# Use java file for a xml layout file used in a dialog box

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use a `.java` file to perform actions for a `.xml` layout. I have used this layout for a dialog box. I have linked the `.java` file to that layout but it doesn't seem to work at all.

This is the MainActivity

```
package com.example.ayush.projectfive;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
AlertDialog.Builder alrt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    alrt = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alrt.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    alrt.setTitle("Login");
    alrt.setCancelable(false);
    alrt.setView(R.layout.mylayout);
    alrt.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alrt.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alrt.show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is the activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ayush.projectfive.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EXIT"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

This is the dialog box layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/button3" />
```

This is the .java file I'd like to link with.

```
package com.example.ayush.projectfive;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Second extends AppCompatActivity{

EditText et, et2;
Button btn2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s1 = et.getText().toString();
            String s2 = et.getText().toString();
            if(s1.equals(s2)){
                Toast.makeText(Second.this, "Login Successful",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Second.this,Third.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{

            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: make sure that your java file extends Dialog and implements onclicklistener, if you post the code problem will be easily solved

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Comment: Well, I have added the code. If you can help now, please.

Comment: Why do you move to your activity Second with an Exit button?

Comment: Can you describe in a few more words your expected result?

Comment: Do you want both the exit button and the dialog box to appear in the main activity?

Comment: "*need to use a .java file to perform actions for a .xml layout*"... That's a large use-case of the XML & Java interoperability in Android... What exactly is your expected behavior?

Comment: to see the login dialog box when starting the app..

Answer (score 0):

just add `alrt.show();` in your `MainActivity.java` e.g. here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
AlertDialog.Builder alrt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    alrt = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alrt.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    alrt.setTitle("Login");
    alrt.setCancelable(false);
    alrt.setView(R.layout.mylayout);

    alrt.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alrt.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
```

> alrt.show();

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: delete it from there.

Comment: What if OP intended on showing the dialog on a button click?

Comment: let´s wait and see what his intention is. I already asked for a description of the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the .java file I'd like to link with [...]
>
> `public class Second extends AppCompatActivity{`

Okay... That's what this code does

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
startActivity(i);
```

If you are trying to use the views that are contained within the dialog box and respond to the buttons there to login, then you need to remove the button from the activity, add `alrt.show()` in the `onCreate` instead of `onClick` and move the Activity start code into the dialog's `onClick` handlers.

It's also worth mentioning that the object is a builder, so you can do this

```
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
final EditText editUsername = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
// TODO: Get other views from mylayout.xml

new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setTitle("Login")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setView(dialogView)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String username = editUsername.getText().toString();
            // TODO: Get more variables
            // TODO: Verify credentials
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null)
    .show();
```

And, as stated earlier, remove `btn.setOnClickListener`